# Change form submit action and then submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to add a button to my form that would essentially run some different php code than my regular form submission code, that would, instead of emailing me the form, convert my page into a nice pdf ready to print. I have everything working except that pressing the button is giving me an error.

Firebug says :
[image]

Here's the code:

```
<form id="adaugareanunt" name="adaugareanunt" action="mailerPDF.php" method="post">
    <table width="535" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3">
         <tr class="TrDark">
         //... more form code
```

and for the button:

```
<div style="text-align:right"><img src="images/print-button.png" onClick="chgAction()" width="60px" height="20px"></div>
```

with the script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function chgAction()
        {
            document.getElementById["adaugareanunt"].action = "mailerXFDF.php";
            document.getElementById["adaugareanunt"].submit();
            document.getElementById["adaugareanunt"].action = "mailerPDF.php";

        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Use round brackets to get the  [*MDN:* document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```js
const EL_form = document.getElementById("form"); 
EL_form.action = "someOtherURL.php";
EL_form.submit();
// PS! Make sure you don't have any name="submit" inputs in your form
```

#### Don't use inputs with `name="submit"`

Make also sure, if you want to use the `.submit()` method - that you **don't have any `name="submit"` input** in your form. Call it differently if really needed like i.e `name="button_submit"`.

**Here's the issue with `name="submit"` inputs:** they overtake the function `submit` since any element with a set `name` attribute becomes a property of that form Element.
Example of the problem:

```js
// EXAMPLE OF THE ISSUE:

const EL_form = document.getElementById("form");

// Why does EL_form.submit() not work?

console.log(EL_form.submit);   // It's the actual INPUT with name="submit"
console.log(EL_form.submit()); // Therefore the "Not a function" error.
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error on the submit line. 'document.getElementById("adaugareanunt").submit();'

'TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function'

Comment: Fixed it like this: `document.getElementById("submit").click();`

Answer (score 10):

```
document.getElementById["adaugareanunt"]
```

change to

```
document.getElementById("adaugareanunt")
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function chgAction()
        {
              document.getElementById("adaugareanunt").action ="mailerXFDF.php";
              document.getElementById("adaugareanunt").submit();
              document.getElementById("adaugareanunt").action ="mailerPDF.php";

        }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the block brackets : []

To

The round brackets : ()

Square brackets means new Array.

```
var ar = newArray( " a " , " b " ) ; 
var ar = [ " a " , " b " ] ;
```